# Permute inputs of neural network and expect different outputs?

Tags: multilayer-perceptrons, input-layer

My question is about if it makes sense to define a function (MLP) that takes two feature vectors f1 and f2. However, I want `MLP(f1, f2) != MLP(f2, f1)`. I believe this should be right since in the first case f1 is multiplied by a different subset of weights as in the second case (same for f2). However, conceptually, does it make sense to design an MLP with this behaviour?

Also, as an extra note I would also like `MLP(f1, f1) == MLP(f1, f2)`. I.e, the first feature vector *mandates*. You might wonder, then why I don't just always input the first feature vector? The idea is that extra feature vectors should work as an extra signal to improve the MLP performance.

Comment: _extra feature vectors should work as an extra signal to improve the MLP performance_ then it can't be true that $MLP(f1, f1) == MLP(f1, f2)$